# iCloud login loading

Tags: icloud, password, login

I changed my Apple ID password and want to login to iCloud with my Mac. 
Entered password, and now it shows me loading and I can't do anything: neither restart the computer nor cancel the request.

[image]

Please help, it has been over 10 minutes . . .

Comment: If you feel the need you can force restart your computer using Command-Control-Eject/Power Button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force restart it either by holding down the power button or using command+control+power button.

Comment: Ok. I fixed. Thank you. But can you explain why it stopped ? now all works well, but I have some problems with my icloud account. It shows me that I used all storage and havent any space there, after deleting big information from icloud drive same message appears.

Comment: @Gor Afraid I don't know.